# safe dynamic_cast from c-Structure?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have some C-structures that are used through some algorithms that link together c++ parts.

On the input end there is a c++ structure that inherits from the c structure to add some members. at the output end there are some  components that also may require this data.

Is there a safe way to detect if this C structure actually is the mentioned c++ class? maybe by making c++ child classes polymorphic and using dynamic casts?

```
struct Cstruct{
  int someData;
};


class CPPclass: public Cstruct{
  CPPclass(){};
  int someMoreData;
};
```

so maybe something like

```
class CPPclass: public Cstruct{
  virtual ~CPPclass(){};
  CPPclass(){};
  int someMoreData;
};

void test(Cstruct* i_c){
  auto cpp = dynamic_cast<CPPclass*>(i_c);   // < does not work, because Cstruct is not polymorphic
  if(cpp){
      // da;
  }
}
```

but maybe?:

```
class CPPclassHelper: public Cstruct{
  virtual ~CPPclassHelper(){};
  CPPclassHelper(){};
  int someMoreData;
};

class CPPclass: public CPPclassHelper{
  virtual ~CPPclassHelper(){};
};

void test(Cstruct* i_c){
  auto cpph = static_cast<CPPclassHelper*>(i_c); 
  auto cpp = dynamic_cast<CPPclass*>(cpph );   
  if(cpp){
      // da;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "C-structure", you mean a struct declared `extern "C"` and used in some existing C library or interface, right? Which can't change for compatibility reasons?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to compile `Cstruct` as C code, but you want to be able to determine later if a `Cstruct *` is actually pointing to a `CPPclass` object using something like `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Useless `extern "C"`has not any influence on structure definitions. It just influences the calling conventions of functions

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question. What do you mean by "C" structure? Is it the same thing as a regular `struct` in C++? Do you have to share it with some C code? Is it _owned_ by an external C interface, or can you change it?

Comment: A "C struct"  (aka one specified as `extern "C"`) cannot be used polymorphically, so a pointer to one cannot be used in a `dynamic_cast`.   The only way would be for the "C struct" to contain some data that your code can check (e.g. a flag, a void pointer).   The onus is on the programmer to use that data appropriately   i.e. it is not "safe" by various definitions

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain the type information yourself. Use a static set of all pointers to `Cstruct` that are bases of `CPPclass`. Insert the base in all constructors of `CPPclass` and remove in the destructor. Safe cast can then be implemented using a lookup into that set.

Here is an example:

```
struct CPPclass: Cstruct{
    CPPclass(){
        bases.insert(this);
    };
    CPPclass(const CPPclass&){
        bases.insert(this);
    };
    CPPclass(CPPclass&&){
        bases.insert(this);
    };
    ~CPPclass(){
        bases.erase(this);
    };

    static CPPclass* safe_cast(Cstruct* c) {
        auto it = bases.find(c);
        return it == bases.end()
            ? nullptr
            : static_cast<CPPclass*>(*it);
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_set<Cstruct*> bases;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    CPPclass cpp;
    Cstruct  c;

    Cstruct* ptr_cpp = &cpp;
    Cstruct* ptr_c   = &c;

    std::cout << CPPclass::safe_cast(ptr_cpp) << '\n'; // some address equal to &cpp
    std::cout << CPPclass::safe_cast(ptr_c)   << '\n'; // null
}
```